# Decompose string into substrings

Tags: python, regex

I have strings that contain white-space and punctuation characters that I want to decompose into individual characters. However, I want to avoid breaking up certain sub-strings that have a specific meaning such as `...` or `-` or `\n\r`.

For example, the string `\n\r\n... .. - -..` should be decomposed into

```
['\n', '\r\n', '...', '.', '.', ' - ', '-', '.', '.']
```

I've tried using `re.findall()` and `re.split()` but without success. The following produced so far the best results (I included only some of the delimiters here to make the example shorter):

```
delimiters = [
    r'\r\n',
    r'\n',
    r' - ',
    r' ',
    r'...', 
    r'\.',
]
pattern = re.compile(r'(' + r'|'.join(delimiters) + r')')
match = pattern.split('\n\r\n... .. - -..')
print([m for m in match if m])
```

which gives

```
['\n', '\r\n', '...', ' ', '.. ', '- -', '.', '.']
```

This is very close but I don't understand why `..`  and `- -` are matched.

Comment: Did you mean to match dots with `...`? Then escape them, `\.\.\.` or `\.{3}`

Comment: Note that you may discard blank items if you replace `if m` with `if m.strip()`

Comment: Escaping dots worked. The blank items I actually want to keep. Thanks!!